stars and st_apply: summarise NetCDF for each timestamp and create multiple new attributes
I have a stars-object like this one:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qcMATPjSyw-Rk9WpfFTa1rpr7dtOUxsu/view?usp=drive_link
It looks like this:
nc = read_stars("~/Desktop/SPARTACUS - Spatial Dataset for Climate in Austria Datensatz_202301_202410.nc") %>% 
  rename(value=1) %>% 
  mutate(value=as.numeric(value))
nc

stars object with 3 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
       Min. 1st Qu. Median     Mean 3rd Qu.  Max.
value   5.2    54.8   86.7 105.2152   131.6 651.3
dimension(s):
     from  to offset delta                   refsys                    values x/y
x       1 136 487000  1000 ETRS89 / Austria Lambert                      NULL [x]
y       1  99 491000 -1000 ETRS89 / Austria Lambert                      NULL [y]
time    1  22     NA    NA                  POSIXct 2023-01-01,...,2024-10-01   

Now I want to find some aggregates for each pixel.
1. For each pixel how often was the value above 0
2. When (which date) was the last time a value was above 0
I think I can compute both statistics with two calls to st_apply like this (although I'd prefer to get the date in the second directly instead of the index, yet I don't know how to do that...)
times = st_apply(nc, 1:2, function(x){
  ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x > 0))}, .fname = "times"
)

last_time = st_apply(nc, 1:2, function(x) {
  ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(which(x > 0)))}, .fname = "last_time")
)

Now I have two star-objects with each two dimensions and one attribute. I don't know how to combine the attributes.
And the best case would be to compute the two statistics in one call to st_apply. I'm thinking something similar to the summarise from dplyr where I can compute as many summaries for each group as I want. Is that possible with stars? Am I missing something obvious and should use other functions?
